# C++ class copy constructor initialization

Tags: c++, class, copy-constructor

I am new to C++, and I am confused about why the copy constructor can be initialized on line 70 as `const Animal c = b;`. But the implementation is `Animal::Animal(const Animal & a)`, so why would `Animal c = b` be equivalent to `Animal c (b)`?

Below is the code:

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <string>

const std::string unk = "unknown";
const std::string clone_prefix = "clone-";

// -- interface --
class Animal {
    std::string a_type = "";
    std::string a_name = "";
    std::string a_sound = "";
public:
    Animal();   // default constructor
    Animal(const std::string & type, const std::string & name, const std::string & sound);
    Animal(const Animal &); // copy constructor
    ~Animal();  // destructor
    Animal & operator = (const Animal &); // copy operator
    void print() const;
};

// -- implementation --
Animal::Animal() : a_type(unk), a_name(unk), a_sound(unk) {
    puts("default constructor");
}

Animal::Animal(const std::string & type, const std::string & name, const std::string & sound)
: a_type(type), a_name(name), a_sound(sound) {
    puts("constructor with arguments");
}

Animal::Animal(const Animal & a) {
    puts("copy constructor");
    a_name = clone_prefix + a.a_name;
    a_type = a.a_type;
    a_sound = a.a_sound;
}

Animal::~Animal() {
    printf("destructor: %s the %s\n", a_name.c_str(), a_type.c_str());
    a_name = "";
    a_type = "";
    a_sound = "";

}

Animal & Animal::operator = (const Animal & o) {
    puts("assignment operator");
    if(this != &o) {
        a_name = clone_prefix + o.a_name;
        a_type = o.a_type;
        a_sound = o.a_sound;
    }
    return *this;
}

void Animal::print () const {
    printf("%s the %s says %s\n", a_name.c_str(), a_type.c_str(), a_sound.c_str());
}

int main() {
    
    Animal a;
    a.print();
    
    const Animal b("goat", "bob", "baah");
    b.print();
    
    const Animal c = b;
   // const Animal c (b);
    
    c.print();
    
    a = c;
    a.print();
    
    puts("end of main");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: @Jason I have understood nothing. The question does not make a sense.

Comment: What part is confusing you? `const Animal c = b;` (typically) initializes `c` via a constructor call with the initializer (`b`) as argument. Overload resolution chooses the copy constructor.

Comment: Do you wonder why it isn't an assignment? Because that's how the language is defined. `Animal c = b;` is equivalent to `Animal c{b};`.

Comment: Thank you Paul! but logically, it just does not make any sense, why would ' Animal c = b' is the same as 'Animal c (b)' in my code. :(

Comment: @Jason Why should it not be? Do you expect `Animal c = b;` to have a different meaning? If so, what?

Comment: There are several things in C++ that have alternative syntax. They are logically equivalent and interchangeable. Here's another one `c=b;` is equivalent to `c.operator=(b)`.

Comment: @Sam thank you so much. that makes so much sense now!

Comment: @SamVarshavchik: And I'm sure `a[b]` is the same as `b[a]` so `6 ["Hello world!"]` is valid! Yeah, C/C++ is weird at times, hence the IOCCC!

Comment: I think your confusion is warranted.  And the situation is deeper than what you've seen so far.  If you are interested and have an hour to kill, obligatory [The Nightmare of Initialization in C++](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7DTlWPgX6zs) by Nicolai Josuttis.

Comment: @Skizz • The IOCCC is for **C**, not **C++**.  There is no IOC++CC for the same reason there is no IOPerlCC.

Comment: IOCCC is the sound people make after having drunk far, far too much. Which about right when you consider the winning code looks like the stuff you write after having drunk far, far too much.

Comment: I'm occasionally chastised for purportedly too much drinking. From now on I'll cite @user4581301 's insightful analysis as proof to the contrary.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik • 200 proof to the contrary.

Comment: @Eljay: I know, but most C programs will compile using a C++ compiler and I was just pointing out that flexible (!) language features can produce intresting code (eg, the IOCCC for C). The first IOCCC was in 1984, about the time C++was invented, and it hasn't changed to encompass other languages. You can probably write even more obfuscated code in C++ than you could in C (thanks in part to things like operator overloading).